# How do I instantiate a class without an implicit/explicit constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

> Edit. This was my first question in stackoverflow :) thanks a lot for answers. but It seems I did not clarify question clearly.  I will open new question with full code.

Can someone help understanding this code?

I have Foo class which does not have constructor and all of its methods are virtual.
I only got headers.

```
class Bar;
class USER_API IFoo
{
public:

    virtual ~IFoo() {}

    virtual uint32_t GetWidth() const = 0;
    // more virtual methods...
};

class USER_API Foo
    : public IFoo
{
public:
    virtual Bar *GetBar() = 0;
};
```

It has no constructor, so I can not use `auto ptrFoo = new Foo` method.
**Is this mean `Foo` class does not have implicit/explicit constructor?**

**If yes, how can I prevent calling of default constructor?**
The only way I know of is to make the constructor a protected member. But in this header no declaration of c'tor.

I can get pointer of `Foo` instance from `GetFoo()` method in `Bar` class below.

```
class Foo;
class USER_API Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
    virtual ~Bar();

    Foo *GetFoo();
    const Foo *GetFoo() const;
}
```

**I am curious about, How Bar.cpp create and have instance of Foo?**
What I'm guessing is that Bar.cpp has a class that inherits from class `Foo`.

Any hint would be appreciated..

Comment: Unless you have explicitly declared or deleted them default constructors both `IFoo` and `Foo` will have a default constructor. It will be implicitly generated to default-initialise any members or bases (or do nothing if no members or bases).  You can't initialise your classes because both have pure virtual functions (virtual functions that a derived class *must* override, if the derived class is to be instantiable).   To suppress generation  of a default constructor, then do `IFoo() = delete` (for class `IFoo`) in C++11 or (before C++11) declare `IFoo()` private but don't define it.

Comment: *It has no constructor*  It has a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo` does have an implicit constructor, because it is neither explicitly defined nor explicitly deleted.

You can make the implicit (default) constructor protected by just writing that.

```
 protected:
    Foo() = default;
```

Comment: first, Thanks you for quick reply.  
but This is an header of some library. and I can not find protected ```Foo() = default;``` constructor entire header..

Comment: @JaeMinKim: If it is not your code, and you cannot change `Foo`, then you cannot prevent `Foo::Foo()`  from being called.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you don't want a class to be instantiated you need to make private its constructor. Therefore nobody will be able to call it and therefore make instance of it.
For create an instance you would need then to define a static member function that invoke the private constructor (since member functions of a class have access to private members).

The other option is the class to be abstract, as your class **IFoo**. An abstract class cannot be instantiated although sometimes is remarked declaring the constructor protected:

```
class Base_class {
  public:
    virtual ~Base_class() = 0;
  protected:
    Base_class() {}
};
```

In your case, Foo is not abstract and its Constructor is not declared, so it has a default constructor and it can be instantiated.
If you don't have access to Foo you can not modify this behavior

Comment: Thanks, but no constructor is declared. At first, I guessed there should be a default constructor. but ```new Foo;``` is failed with 'no appropriated default constructor'. I don't understand how this can be possible..